# Blocky behavior when converting bgr to hsv in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, hsv

I'm trying to convert an bgr mat to an hsv mat for some detection, but the hsv image keeps coming out blocky. Here is my code in c++:

```
int main() {
    const int device = 1;
    VideoCapture capture(device);
    Mat input;
    int key;
    if(!capture.isOpened()) {
        printf("No video recording device under device number %i found. Aborting program...\n", device);
        return -1;
    }
    namedWindow("Isolation Test", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    while(1) {
        capture >> input;
        cvtColor(input, input, CV_BGR2HSV);
        imshow("Isolation Test", input);
        key = static_cast<int>(waitKey(10));
        if(key == 27)
            break;
    }
    destroyWindow("Isolation Test");
    return 0;
}
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjBmi.jpg) is a snapshot of what the output looks like. the input does not look blocky when I comment out the cvtColor. What is the problem and what should I do to fix it?

Comment: It is possible that the image is blocky before the conversion but it is just harder to detect that. JPEG/MPEG compression are utilizing imperfections of our "visual pipeline" and by that creating many artifacts that are hard to detect, When you are showing the image with false colors (for example the HSV channels) they sometimes become very visible. You can save the image in a lossless format (png/tiff) and investigate the actual values with a color checker.

Comment: i can even reproduce that in 3.0 (master). also with different webcam models/drivers. and it only happens with webcam capture, not with imread().  nice puzzle ;)

Comment: @scribblemaniac, you probably want to [make an issue here](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/issues)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggested an explanation in the comments part, but decided to actually verify my assumption and explain a little bit about the `HSV` color space.

There is no problem in the code nor in OpenCV's `cvtColor`. the "blocky" artifacts exist in the `RGB` image, but are not noticeable. All of the JPEG family compression algorithms produce these artifacts. The reason we usually don't see them is that the algorithms "exploit" weaknesses in our visual system and compress more stuff that we are not very sensitive to.

I converted the image back to `RGB` using OpenCV`s`cvtColor` and the artifacts magically disappeared (images are below).

The `HSV` color space in particular has several characteristics that exaggerate these artifacts. The important of which is probably the fact that wherever the `V` channel (Value/Luminance) is very low, the `H` & `S` channels are very unstable and are quite meaningless. In the extreme: `[128,255,0] == [0,0,0]`.

So very small and unnoticeable compression artifacts in the dark areas of the image become very prominent with the false colors of the `HSV` color space.

If you want to use the `HSV` color space as feature space for color comparison keep in mind that if `V` is very low, `H & S` are quite meaningless. That is also true for very low `S` values that make the `H` value meaningless (`[0,0,100] == [128,0,100]`).

BTW. also keep in mind that the `H` channel is cyclic and the difference between `H == 0` and `H == 255` is only one gray level.

- False colors "blocky" `HSV` image posted in the question 
  [image: HSV image posted by @scribblemaniac]
- Image converted back to `RGB` using `cvtColor`
  [image: Same image after conversion back to RGB]

Comment: Thanks for the follow up it has helped me out quite a bit. I get what your you're saying, I guess I'll just have to adjust my ranges accordingly to compensate for this.

Comment: no problem, I you can simply use the RGB color space (although it is not very popular) or define a distance function in HSV that is robust to low V or S values.

Answer (score 0):

I think this happen because the `imshow` function will always interpret the image as a simple RGB or BGR image. So you need to change back HSV to BGR using `cvtColor(input,input,CV_HSV2BGR)` before show image.